# Should I community wiki answers to my own questions?

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

When I am answering my own question should I make it community wiki? In particular, should I do this when:

- I only have a partial solution
- I have a solution complete by itself, but I am looking for alternatives
- I already know the answer and don't believe that anyone else needs to post anything on it, but I am just posting the solution for the benefit of other users

Comment: You can associate your accounts and get a 100 points rep boost here.

Comment: Thanks, will do this eventually

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think that any of the reasons is coercive for wikifying your answer. Your own answer is as valid and valuable as all others, and you might as well earn reputation from it.

For the first reason: if it is only a small part, you might want to include it in the answer. "This is what I have so far and tried up to now" style.

As SO/SF/SU want to be a repository of computer knowledge in three facets, answering your own question not only is ok, but encouraged.

Comment: I fully agree with this. Still, in case you feel you definitely won't deserve any rep from a particular answer, or if you specifically want to encourage others to improve it, by all means do make it cw.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Ralph, those reasons alone don't put any burden on you to wikify your answer.  I think I would only wikify my answers when:

- I am **presenting alternatives** on which I want answerers to use their votes to express a subjective opinion.  This usually means your question is a poll, which probably means the question isn't appropriate except in very exceptional cases.
- When there's a high probability my **answer is incorrect, poor style, or otherwise unpopular**, but I am including it for illustrative purposes.  I might CW the answer to protect myself from the rep loss when people decide to downvote that answer.  After all, they are protecting others from finding my wrong answer and thinking it's right.